# R CMD INSTALL error: Unexpected Symbol in test_load_package() function

Tags: r

### Issue:

I'm just trying to build a few packages from source and am running into an error

> Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::.test_load_package('rbenchmark',
>   '\per-homedrive1.corp.something.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell"

Full output below:

```
C:\ROracle>R CMD INSTALL --build --merge-multiarch rbenchmark_1.0.0.tar.gz

install for i386

* installing to library '\\per-homedrive1.corp.something.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell/R/win-library/2.15'
* installing *source* package 'rbenchmark' ...
** package 'rbenchmark' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::.test_load_package('rbenchmark', '\\per-homedrive1.corp.something.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell"
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '\\per-homedrive1.corp.something.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell/R/win-library/2.15/rbenchmark'
```

### Question:

- Is the error coming from the apostrophe (`'`) from `O'Dell` in the path?
- If yes, is it a bug since it isn't escaping the apostrophe in the directory?
- Is it trying to install into my default library?
- If yes, can I change the library as a parameter in `R CMD INSTALL`?
- If I can't specify the library, should I remove that library altogether?

### Extra Info:

Here's the output of `.libPaths()`

```
[1] "\\\\per-homedrive1.corp.something.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell/R/win-library/2.15"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library"                                            
[3] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, the error comes from the apostrophe - R can't know that this doesn't end the path, but is part of it. Try it without it and it should work I guess. One solution might be also to use this kind of quotation instead `" "`, maybe this works out as well, because then the apostrophe doesn't end it any more...

EDIT: In order to install a package `foo` via command line to an specific library folder via command line you can use

```
R CMD build foo
R CMD INSTALL -l /home/daniel/myPkg/ foo_1.0.tar.gz
```

This means in your case this should work:

`R CMD INSTALL --build --merge-multiarch -l C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library rbenchmark_1.0.0.tar.gz`

Comment: The problem is that I'm not actually writing the function... it's being run as part of `R CMD INSTALL --build` So I probably need to change the default library (but can't figure out how)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood then the question. I edited my answer and added there how to specify the installation path in `R CMD INSTALL`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That did the trick... I changed it to another R library (in C:\Program Files\...) but it didn't like the space in the url path. So I tried C:\test\ and it worked fine. So apparently it doesn't have to be an existing library, just any old folder (so long as the folder doesn't have an apostrophe or a space in the name!)

Comment: I am not sure, but if there is a whitespace in the path, it might help to quote it, like `-l "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/libraries"`. (In fact I wondered a bit, I thought I copied the path from your post including the quotation). But happy to hear that it worked out.

Comment: I had it quoted in the CMD prompt.. something still didn't like it