# Cannot download packages from GitHub from unexpected symbol

Tags: r, github

I'm trying to download [CMRnet package](https://github.com/matthewsilk/CMRnet) using

```
remotes::install_github("matthewsilk/CMRnet", build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

and I keep getting this error:

*byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

Error: unexpected symbol in "setwd('C:/Users/KYLA'S" Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'CMRnet' removing 'C:/Users/Kyla's XPS/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/CMRnet'
Error: Failed to install 'CMRnet' from GitHub:   (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/KYLA'S~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQP7KSL/file2484399a2b2b/CMRnet_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status*

When I try

```
remotes::install_github("matthewsilk/CMRnet", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library")
```

I get the same error. Any help would be much appreciated! It seems that it doesn't like the ' in Kyla's, but I can't rename a user folder and adding another user doesn't seem to work either. I don't have any issues with installing a package using install.packages()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129888/r-cmd-install-error-unexpected-symbol-in-test-load-package-function

Comment: The problem might be with installing packages *from source* (on Windows, installing from binary is the default when installing from CRAN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> Error: unexpected symbol in "setwd('C:/Users/KYLA'S" Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading

this error is probably related to the apostrophe in the directory as the path name is cut off where it appears in the path string.

do you get the same error when you try installing it under another user?
and when you define the lib to `lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"` do you get the same error or get an error telling you that the directory is not writable ( this is due to permission restriction)

try this

- right click on r or rstudio and `run as administrator`
- run the following:

```
remotes::install_github("matthewsilk/CMRnet", lib="C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.3\\library")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The apostrophe was the issue, I made another new user without any spaces or apostrophes and was able to do what you said and run as an administrator: remotes::install_github("matthewsilk/CMRnet", lib="C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.3\\library"

Comment: FWIW this bug in R has been fixed in the development version as of about a month ago (will presumably be in the version to be released in April ...)